# Eventbrite API v3 Remove an Organizer

Tags: api, eventbrite

I have looked through the docs and see no mention on removing organizers. How do I remove an organizer via the Eventbrite v3 API?

Answer (score 0):

According to Eventbrite support, there is no capability to remove organizers (or venues) at this time. These methods are on the roadmap with no commitment as to when they will be released.